# laravel Foreach nested

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following arrays:

Blade code:

```php
@foreach($allediensten as $alledienstens)
    @foreach($beschikbaarheid as $beschikbaar)
        @if($beschikbaar->job_id !== $alledienstens->id)
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="{{$alledienstens->id}}" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
                <td id="takenid">{{$alledienstens->id}}</td>
                <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($alledienstens->date)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
                <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($alledienstens->starttijd)->format('H:i')}}</td>
                <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($alledienstens->eindtijd)->format('H:i')}}</td>
                <td>{{$alledienstens->kamernummer}}</td>
                <td>{{$alledienstens->aantalsurveillanten}}</td>
                <td>{{$alledienstens->locatie}}</td>
                <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($alledienstens->beschikbaartot)->format('d-m-Y H:i')}}</td>
                <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($alledienstens->accepttot)->format('d-m-Y H:i')}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Array:

```php
1: [{"job_id":1},{"job_id":2}]

2: {"id":1,"user_id":3,"vaardigheid":"TDV","taal":"Nederlands","digitaal":"Ja","ervaring":"Meer dan 2 jaar","date":"2019-04-05","type":"Decentraal","starttijd":"19:15:00","eindtijd":"20:15:00","kamernummer":"H1.03","locatie":"test","beschikbaartot":"2019-04-11 00:00:00","accepttot":"2019-04-11 16:43:00","status":"uitgezonden","cronstatus":"beschikbaaropgeven","opmerking":null,"created_at":"2019-04-21 14:39:54","updated_at":"2019-04-21 22:26:28"},
{"id":2,"user_id":3,"vaardigheid":"TDV","taal":"Nederlands","digitaal":"Ja","ervaring":"Meer dan 2 jaar","date":"2019-04-05","type":"Decentraal","starttijd":"19:15:00","eindtijd":"20:15:00","kamernummer":"H1.03","locatie":"test","beschikbaartot":"2019-04-11 00:00:00","accepttot":"2019-04-11 16:43:00","status":"uitgezonden","cronstatus":"beschikbaaropgeven","opmerking":null,"created_at":"2019-04-21 14:39:54","updated_at":"2019-04-21 22:26:28"},
{"id":3,"user_id":3,"vaardigheid":"TDV","taal":"Nederlands","digitaal":"Ja","ervaring":"Meer dan 2 jaar","date":"2019-04-05","type":"Decentraal","starttijd":"19:15:00","eindtijd":"20:15:00","kamernummer":"H1.03","locatie":"test","beschikbaartot":"2019-04-11 00:00:00","accepttot":"2019-04-11 16:43:00","status":"uitgezonden","cronstatus":"beschikbaaropgeven","opmerking":null,"created_at":"2019-04-21 14:39:54","updated_at":"2019-04-21 22:26:28"}]
```

Result: this give me the result id 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 is showing.

if looking at the array this must give result: id 3 only.

Comment: Can you Conform `beschikbaarheid ` is `[{"job_id":1},{"job_id":2}]`

Comment: Yes thats the result of that array

Comment: Now Check My answer for solution

Answer (score 0):

What mistake you did is checking `"id":1` is exist in `[{"job_id":1},{"job_id":2}]` full array so it returns true when checking condition `id:1 !== job_id:2` like wise all

Check below answer it's working for me

```
/*
    $beschikbaarheid[] = (object) array("job_id" => "1"); 
    $beschikbaarheid[] = (object) array("job_id" => "2");
    $allediensten[] = (object) array("id" => "1","user_id"=>"3"); 
    $allediensten[] = (object) array("id" => "2","user_id"=>"3"); 
    $allediensten[] = (object) array("id" => "3","user_id"=>"3"); */

    $idexist=false;
    foreach($allediensten as $alledienstens)
    {
        $idexist = checkexist($alledienstens->id);
        if($idexist==false)
        {
            echo" not exist "; // Here Your code goes if "id" is not exist in "job_id"
            $idexist=false;
        }
    }
    function checkexist($job_id){
        global $beschikbaarheid;
        foreach($beschikbaarheid as $beschikbaar){
          if($beschikbaar->job_id == $job_id){
              return true;
          }
      }  
    }
```

What you do is `once it's exist you have to exit for further process`